# Given a positive integer, determine if it's the nth Fibonacci number for some n

Tags: python-3.x, fibonacci

I try to find out the index of a certain Fibonacci number. However my program returned to me this result "Your program took too long to execute. Check your code for infinite loops, or extra input requests" after typing in `1134903171`.

```
num = 1
num_prev = 1
n = int(input())
i = 1
if n < 2:
  print(1, 2)
else:
  while i <= n + 2:
    num_prev, num = num, num + num_prev
    i += 1
    if n == num:
      print(i + 1)
      break
    elif i == n + 3:
      print(-1)
      #break`
```

Comment: the python interpreter never responds with `Your program took too long to execute...` where are you trying to run this? what have you tried to speed up your program?

Comment: @hiroprotagonist It's `num_prev, num = num, num + num_prev`, not `num = num`. That's a tuple assignment. OP I hope you learned the importance of putting spaces around your operators.

Comment: @FHTMitchell ooops, you are right; those are commas, not semicolons (which would have been a syntax error anyway). my bad. deleted comment.

Comment: Thank you dear friends. I was using repl.it to do some exercise online. I know there could be several method for solving this question.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys. The problem of last code is that: if the number isn't a Fibonacci number and meanwhile it is too large, it will took to many loops for the calculation. As I used a web compiler to calculate, they do not allow such "infinity" loop to operate. Then I used a math methode to limite the loop.

```
import math
N=int(input())
root1=math.sqrt(5*N*N+4)
root2=math.sqrt(5*N*N-4)
i=1
num, num_prev = 1, 1
if root1%1==0 or root2%1==0:
  while i <= N+2:
    num_prev,num = num,(num+num_prev)
    i+=1
    if N==num:
      print(i+1)
      break
else:
  print(-1)

But the best answer could be:
prev, next = 1, 1
index = 2
possible_fib = int(input())
while possible_fib > next:
   prev, next = next, prev + next
   index += 1
 if possible_fib == next:
   print(index)
 else:
   print(-1)
```